# ¿como Asignarle imagenes diferentes de la galeria a 3 ElevatedButton.?

Tags: flutter, vscode, dart

Hola y muy buenas noches, actualmente estoy trabajando con un StatefulWidget, el cual contiene el botón de la cámara y 3 ElevatedButton los cuales apuntan a la galería para seleccionar las imágenes, el problema que tengo es que cuando selecciono una imagen, en los 3 se me selecciona la imagen, me gustaría saber como seleccionar 1 imagen para cada ElevatedButton. dejo el código para tener la idea de lo que tengo elaborado.

```
void _getImage({required ImageSource source}) async {
final file = await _picker.pickImage(
  source: source,
  imageQuality: 50,
  maxHeight: 600,
  maxWidth: 900,
);

if (file != null) {
  setState(
    () {
      imageFile = File(file.path);
    },
  );
}
```

}

```
 ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              _getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
            },
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 45,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              backgroundImage:
                  imageFile == null ? null : FileImage(imageFile!),
              child: imageFile == null
                  ? const Icon(
                      Icons.add_photo_alternate,
                      size: 30.0,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    )
                  : null,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: si los 3 tienen la misma condición y la misma variable = imageFile , entonces en los 3 mostrará eso, agrega más código para saber que estás haciendo

Comment: si los 3 ElevatedButton están apuntando a la misma galería, creo que tendría que hacer alguna tipo de condición, pero no estoy muy seguro en que tipo de condición, me refiero cuando presione 1 botón y llame esa imagen, no me la cambie en los otros botones. 
no agrego mas código ya que es lo mismo me refiero a los ElevatedButton.
por cierto no se si hay algún problema en pegar los otros 2 ElevatedButton.

Comment: quizas necesitas extraer ese button en un widget aparte, asi cada uno tendra sus propias variables . te diria que sigas revisando la documentacion oficial flutter.dev

Comment: creo que esa es una buena idea, creo que probare eso, la verdad me había quedado corto de ideas, pero ya con eso probare, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo crear variables de clase en este caso serían 3:

```
String? path1, path2, path3;
```

Luego en tu función de selección de imagen le mandaría como parámetro una variable de tipo `int id`

```
   void _getImage({required int id,required ImageSource source}) async {
final file = await _picker.pickImage(
  source: source,
  imageQuality: 50,
  maxHeight: 600,
  maxWidth: 900,
);

if (file != null) {
  setState(
    () {
      imageFile = File(file.path);
    },
  );
}
```

Dentro de este método tu harías un `switch case` para determinar en qué botón estás y a que variable le asignaras el valor.

```
if (file != null) {
   swtich(id){
   case 0:
    setState(
    () {
      path1 = File(file.path);
    });
   break;
   case 1:
    setState(
    () {
      path2 = File(file.path);
    });
   break;
   case 2:
    setState(
    () {
      path3 = File(file.path);
    });
   break;
   }
}
```

Espero y este ejemplo te haya servido.